# Bootstrap - show all Typeahead items on focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'd like to show all Typeahead items when the text-input (id="Questions") get focus.
How can I do it?

Javascript:

```
function SetTypeahead() {
    $("#Questions").typeahead({
        minLength: 0,
        source: [
                "Q1?",
                "Q2?",
                "Q3?",
                "@4?"
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Hi John
It works when I start to type, but not only on focus.
The idea is to show all the options on focus.
I read these articles, but have no success on suggestions:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2043 and 
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/3941

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Hi John, about the articles above, I dont understand how to implement this code:    
$input.on('focus', $input.typeahead.bind($input, 'lookup')));

Answer (score 17):

Get the latest bootstrap typeahead plugin v2.1.2 at https://raw.github.com/michaelcox/bootstrap/6789648b36aedaa795f1f5f11b4da6ab869f7f17/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js

This update will allow minLength of zero to enable show all for typeahead

```
<input id="typeaheadField" name="typeaheadField" type="text" placeholder="Start Typing">

$("#typeaheadField").typeahead({
                        minLength: 0,
                        items: 9999,
                        source: ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado", "Oregon"]    
                    });
```

Then you have to attach the onFocus event to your element, because it's not defined by the plugin:

```
$("#typeaheadField").on('focus', $("#typeaheadField").typeahead.bind($("#typeaheadField"), 'lookup'));
```

it's a also a good idea to overwrite the bootstrap typeahead css class locally to set max-height and vertical scroll for the results in case there are too many results.

```
.typeahead {
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Work for me (bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.3.2) but when I try to click the scrollbar typeahead disappear.

Answer (score 3):

*Get the latest version* (***`bootstrap3-typeahead.js v4.0.2`***) *script from Github:* [***Download***](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js)

***Html Code:***

```
<input data-provide="typeahead" id="q" type="text" value="" />
```

***Working JavaScript:***

```
// autocomplete input text
$('#q').typeahead({
    // your json data source
    source: [your json or object here],
    // on click list option set as text value
    autoSelect: true,
    // set minlength 0 to show list on focus
    minLength: 0,
    // set no of items you want here
    items: 20,
    // set true if want to list option on focus
    showHintOnFocus: true
});
```

***Official Document:*** [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

Comment: Hi Neeraj, how do you make it scrollable? Also, when focus, how to automatically select one? For example, I have a list of countries. Say that in the text box is the value *Thailand*. When I click on the text box, it should went to *Thailand* right away. How to archive that? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi @Sam, for the scrollable you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565799/typeahead-scrollable-dropdown-menu link and for the Auto select Input value from the data available, it comes automatically when the user stops the typing on input.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I am using *Bootstrap-3-Typeahead*. I actually found that link, but it doesn't apply to *Bootstrap-3-Typeahead*. I assumed it is not for *Bootstrap-3-Typeahead*?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the $viewValue was null upon selection which was preventing the list from displaying. My solution was to set the filter to an empty string when $viewValue was null.

```
<input type="text"
  ng-model="gear.Value"
  uib-typeahead="gear as gear.Name for gear in gears | filter:$viewValue || ''"
  typeahead-show-hint="true"
  typeahead-min-length="0"
  typeahead-show-hint="true"
  typeahead-editable='false'
  typeahead-focus-first='false'
  class="form-control"
  name="gear"
  ng-required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this over on the bootstrap github:
<strike>https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/5063</strike>

Edit: That link is dead, use the link that Andrew posted: https://github.com/ptnplanet/Bootstrap-Better-Typeahead

Comment: This is the project I used (linked on that pull request): https://github.com/ptnplanet/Bootstrap-Better-Typeahead

Comment: The link you've provided is dead.

Answer (score 1):

For me, working code looks like this:

```
var typeHeadField = $("#typeaheadField");
typeHeadField.typeahead({
                        minLength: 0,
                        items: 9999,
                        source: ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado", "Oregon"]    
                    });
typeHeadField.on('focus', function() {
 $(this).trigger('propertychange');
});
```

In other words, just trigger the event `'propertychange'` on your desired event. And the Typehead autocomplete will open.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/390) from [theophraim's typeahead](https://github.com/theoephraim/typeahead.js), he has included this functionality, but it is yet to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

The last version `v3.1.0` of typeahead had an explicit option

```
showHintOnFocus:true
```

Comment: What is the URL to the project?  The link I see the GitHub only goes to version 0.11: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed issue about it on typeahead github at the following link: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/462

You will find out that, as described by jharding:

> "typeahead.js is meant to complement search boxes that are powered by, for all intents and purposes, an infinite dataset. The sort of functionality proposed here isn't really a great fit for what we want typeahead.js to be. "

Though a previous message by pricey shows how you can implement it.

You can also go for more recent version https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

- Init typeahead

  $("#FinalGrades", context).typeahead({
              minLength: 0,
              items: 10,
              scrollBar: true,
              source: finalGrades
          });
- Trigger textbox event

  ```
  $("#FinalGrades", context).on("keyup focus", function (e) {
      var that = $(this);
      if (that.val().length > 0 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 38) return;
      that.select();
      var dropDown = that.next('.dropdown-menu');
      dropDown.empty();
      $("#FinalGrades", context).val(qualificationNames[0]);
      that.trigger('keyup');
      $.each(finalGrades, function (index, value) {
          var item = '<li data-value="' + value + '" class=""><a href="#">' + value + '</a></li>';
          dropDown.append(item);
      });
      that.val('');
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

WORKS For bootstrap-3-typeahead, the easiest is just to simulate a keyup with backspace (chr8) on focus.

```
$("#people_lookup").typeahead({
    source: people_list,
    minLength: 0
}).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event('keyup', {which: 8}));
});
```