# Typeahead - Scrollable Dropdown Menu

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead

Looks like the CSS isn't working for my Typeahead.
I am trying to reproduce the Scrollable Dropdown Menu like on
https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples

Here is my code:

JS

```
var productList = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('PART_NO'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            //Maybe I need a prefetch
           // prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
            remote: {
                url: 'getProducts/%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#scrollable-dropdown-menu .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'PARTS',
            limit: 10,
            display: 'PART_NO',
            source: productList
        });
```

CSS

```
 #scrollable-dropdown-menu .tt-dropdown-menu {
            max-height: 150px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

I can't see where the .tt-dropdown-menu is?

Cheers,

Mick

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1301). There is an issue with the scrollable dropdown example.

Update your CSS to:

```css
 #scrollable-dropdown-menu .tt-menu {
   max-height: 150px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
document.getElementById(e.target.attributes['aria- 
           activedescendant'].value).scrollIntoView(true)});
```